# Primary key is not starting from 1 after truncating table data

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

in `UserDetails` table. But, once I truncate `UserDetails` table, it is not starting Id value from initial onwards. I didnt give `SEQUENCE` in db, but it is adding as sequence.

Comment: 1) what database are you using? 2) do you see a table hibernate_sequence in your database?

Comment: AUTO says leave it to the JPA provider to do whatever it wants regarding value generation (so it uses a SEQUENCE in your case ... but it could equally have used AUTO_INCREMENT or whatever) and then you, without JPA knowing about it, truncate the table. So it continues to use the SEQUENCE from where it got to. Expected result is to not start from initial. If you want to go about TRUNCATing a table then you also need to remove/reset the SEQUENCE also

Comment: Why this is a problem for you? The only requirement for auto-generated ID is uniqueness. You should not rely on any other property

Answer (score 1):

First, When you use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` annotation the persistence provider will determine values based on the type of the primary key attribute.

This type can be `numerical` or `UUID`. For `numeric` values (Your situation) the **generation** is based on a `sequence` or table `generator`. So the **primary key** values will be unique at the **database level**.

Now let's back to your question.
What you can do is that to finding the generated sequence on your database and re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `AUTO`, if you using hibernate, it will choose one of the `strategies` to generate your id. From the Reference:

> AUTO - either identity column, sequence or table depending on the
>   **underlying DB**.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_DATA")
   @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "my_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "SEQ_DATA")
   private int id;
```

If I am truncating table, I will DROP sequence using,  DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_DATA;
Then I will create SEQ_DATA again.

create sequence SEQ_DATA minvalue 1 maxvalue 999999999999999999999
   start with 1 increment by 1 cache 20;